# beautiful soup unable to scrape website contents

Tags: beautifulsoup

Hi I am trying to do a simple web scrape on this website https://www.sayurbox.com/p/Swallow%20Tepung%20Agar%20Agar%20Tinggi%20Serat%207%20gram

where my code is this:

```
def userAgent(URL):
    ua = UserAgent()
    USER_AGENT = ua.random
    headers = {"User-Agent" : str(USER_AGENT),"Accept-Encoding": "*","Connection": "keep-alive"}
    resp = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")
        print(f'{URL}')
    else:
        print(f'error 200:{URL}')
        urlError = pd.DataFrame({'url':[URL],
                                'date':[dateNow] 
                                })
        urlError.to_csv('errorUrl/errorUrl.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False)
    return soup

soup = userAgent(url)
productTitle = soup.find_all('div', {"class":"InfoProductDetail__shortDesc"})
```

However it is unable to do so, is there something wrong with my code? I tried adding time.sleep to wait for the page to load, however it still does not work. Help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine but the url is dynamic meaning data is generated by JavaScript and requests,BeautifulSoup can't mimic that's you need automation tool something like selenium.Now you can run the code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


url = 'https://www.sayurbox.com/p/Swallow%20Tepung%20Agar%20Agar%20Tinggi%20Serat%207%20gram'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
driver.close()



title=soup.select_one('.InfoProductDetail__shortDesc').text
price= soup.select_one('span.InfoProductDetail__price').text

print(title)
print(price)
```

**Output:**

```
Swallow Tepung Agar Agar Tinggi Serat 7 gram
7.900
```

Comment: hi thanks, can this be run also in streamlit heroku?

Comment: @Hal I've little bit idea about heroko.I'm not sure. Thanks